# extract parent node from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, react-native, parent-child

I have an array like the one below and I want to be able to extract the parent then list the child

```
"options" : {
    "milk" : [ {
      "price" : 0,
      "title" : "Regular"
    }, {
      "price" : 0,
      "title" : "Soy"
    } ],
    "sugar" : [ {
      "price" : 0,
      "title" : 0
    }, {
      "price" : 0,
      "title" : 1
    } ]
```

so that I can display 
Milk
- Regular, 0
- Soy, 0
Sugar
- 0,0
- 1,0

I have been able to pass `this.props.data.options.milk` which allows for the title/price to be render but would like to loop over the options and render what they are and the prices

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the keys of the options object
If your options object looks like this:

```
const obj = {
  "options" : {
    "milk" : [
      {
        "price" : 0,
        "title" : "Regular"
      }, {
        "price" : 0,
        "title" : "Soy"
      }
    ],
    "sugar" : [
      {
        "price" : 0,
        "title" : 0
      }, {
        "price" : 0,
        "title" : 1
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

You can iterate over its properties like so:

```
{
  Object.keys(obj.options).forEach((key) => {
    <Text>{key}</Text>
    <Item data={obj[key]} />
  });
}
```

If data comes from `this.props.data.options`

```
{
  Object.keys(this.props.data.options).forEach((key) => {
    <Text>{key}</Text>
    <Item data={this.props.data.options[key]} />
  });
}
```

And in the `Item` component:

```
{
  this.props.data.forEach((item) => {
    <Text>
      {item.title}: {item.title}
    </Text>
  })
}
```

Comment: How would this work if I am passing the above array via `this.props.data.options`